# get result with jquery ajax from autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery autocomplete and want to retrieve data from php file called **some.php**, in which is only written

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

and here is javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#key").autocomplete({
        source: function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./some.php",
                data: {key: $("#key").val()},
                success: function(result){
                    // what code is needed here to be placed
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

and html by the way =>

```
<input type="text" name="key" id="key">
```

I think script is written correctly , because when I'm writing in **success function alert(result)** it gets "Hello world", but I want it to be in drop down box , how can fix this problem , please help me , thanks :)

Comment: Try...http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: Take a look at the [jQuery UI autocomplete documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote) again. You don't need a function as the source. Just the script that's doing the leg-work.

Comment: can't you show this example pls , I've read but still can't get it well

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#key").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./some.php",
            data: {key: request.term},
            success: function(result){

                response(result);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

`response(result)` will display the autocomplete menu  -- `result` should be an array of items (where each item is a string or an object with `value` or `label` keys).

As SJ GJ mentioned, you can simply set `source: "./some.php"` but then `some.php` needs to be modified to accept the request parameter `term` and return a json array of items.

Comment: I've tried what you have adviced and something is not wrong still , I have this in php file                                           `$array = array("one","two","three");
echo json_encode($array);` and i get strange result in autocomplete

Comment: I'm recieving result like                                                                   `[                                                                   "                                                                    o` and so on , why ?

Comment: you need to return an "id" and a "value" obligatory for the plugin to work. So in the array must use an index : array(1 => 'one');... Imagine if the autocomplete acts as a combobox

Answer (score 1):

try this:

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#key").autocomplete({
        source: "./some.php"
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
$result = array('1' => 'Hello World');

echo json_encode($result);
```